# Generate a report using awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have /etc/fstab entries on 100 servers and i'm trying to write a awk script to identify following.

```
sup01p.abc.com.au | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>

10.15.23.25:/tools /data/store        nfs     defaults,nodev  0       0
10.15.23.25:/kdump01 /data/kdump     nfs     defaults,nodev  0       0
10.15.23.25:/ops        /data/ops  nfs     defaults,nodev  0       0
```

What i need is, first my awk script need to print the domain name, then it should print

```
10.15.23.25:/tools  /data/store - this is an invalid entry,
```

tools incorrectly mounted on store and is not valid, but kdump01 mounted correctly 
on kdump , ops mounted correctly on ops)

How can  i print a report like this using awk or sed ? (print only invalid nfs mounts)

output should be like this

```
sup01p.abc.com.au 
10.15.23.25:/tools /data/store
```

I managed to add the follwing script and it lists servername and mount points

```
cat check |  awk '$1~/com.au/{ print $1 ;next} /10.15.23.25/{print $1;}/data/{print $2;print "======"}'

sup01p.abc.com.au
10.15.23.25:/tools
/data/store
======
10.15.23.25:/kdump01
/data/kdump
=====
10.15.23.25:/ops
/data/ops
======
```

Comment: you'll have to add the code you tried to solve this... NR/FNR equal to 1 will give you first line, as space is default delimiter, `$1` will give you domain name... similarly for lines other than first, get fields you want to compare... you can use regex or split function and compare first/second fields and so on...

Comment: if the "rule" is that `/tools` does not "match" `/data/store` while `/kdump01` does "match" `/data/kdump`, then  you should say so explicitly in you Q. Don't make us guess :-/ . Good luck.

Comment: sorry, yeah  mentioned that. kdump01 mounted correctly on kdump, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution (for your current input):

```
cat check | awk 'NR==1{ print $1; next }{ m=substr($1,index($1,"/")+1); 
            sub(/[^a-z]+/,"",m); if($2!~m) print $1,$2 }'
```

The output:

```
sup01p.abc.com.au
10.15.23.25:/tools /data/store
```